# Simple way to transpose data before passing to functions?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, properties

This is one of the hardest questions I've ever had to title here on SO.  :)  Although the title might not make sense, hopefully the question itself will.

Let's say I have a data structure like a `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`, and that I have functions that then take `List<double>`s as a parameter:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> candy_positions = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
candy_positions.Add( "Godiva", new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 4.0 });
EatCandy( candy_positions["Godiva"]);
...
```

But now I have decided that I don't want to do it this way.  I want to replace my `Dictionary` with a `List<CandyPositions>`, where CandyPositions looks something like this:

```
public class CandyPositions
{
    public double Sees;
    public double Godiva;
    public double Lindt;
}
```

However, I really would like to leave EatCandy() alone.  Obviously, the problem is now that my data doesn't lend itself to be passed directly into the method.  Instead, I have to do something lame like:

```
List<CandyPositions> candy_positions = new List<CandyPositions>();
...
var positions = from x in candy_positions select x.Godiva;
EatCandy( positions.ToList());
```

**every** time I want to call the method.  I'd prefer to be able to do this in a more simple way, like:

```
EatCandy( candy_positions.GetPositionsFor( "Godiva"));
```

where the parameter "Godiva" matches the property name in the CandyPositions class.

After writing this question, I've realized that it isn't really about transposing data -- that part of it can be handled by writing an extension method.  The part I don't know how to do is to pass in a property name, so that the extension method can take this and associate it with a class's property.  I don't want to pass in a string, either, mainly because this will open the door for all sorts of runtime errors.  I know how to make this work by passing "Godiva" to my extension method.  What I really want to pass in is something akin to CandyPositions.Godiva instead.

This question is probably a little confusing, so in summary, I would accept the best of two types of answers:

1. Is there a better way to deal with transposing data, than to use an extension method + some way of accessing a property name?
2. Is there a way to specify the property that I want my extension method to retrieve, other than by a string?

My current extension method looks like this:

```
public static List<double> GetPositions( this List<CandyPositions> positions, string candy_name)
{
    return (from x in positions select x.GetType().GetProperty(candy_name).GetValue(x, null)).Cast<double>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
public static List<double> GetPositions(this List<CandyPositions> positions,
                                        Func<CandyPositions, double> projection)
{
    return positions.Select(projection).ToList();
}
```

and call it with:

```
EatCandy(candyPositions.GetPositions(x => x.Godiva));
```

On the other hand, if you can change `EatCandy` to accept an `IEnumerable<double>` instead, you don't need the extra method - you can just use:

```
EatCandy(candyPositions.Select(x => x.Godiva));
```

without writing an extra method at all.

EDIT: If you need to iterate over two sequences at once, there are two options:

- If you're using .NET 4, you can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method.
- Otherwise, you can basically write your own:

  ```
  using (var iterator1 = sequence1.GetEnumerator())
  using (var iterator2 = sequence2.GetEnumerator())
  {
      while (iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext())
      {
          var value1 = iterator1.Current;
          var value2 = iterator2.Current;
          // Use the values here
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: whoa, very cool approach that hadn't even occurred to me.  Thanks, Jon!  And an off-topic comment -- I'm excited that my order for your new C# book is coming in next week.  :)

Comment: In my particular case, I can't use IEnumerable<double> since I need to access the data by index only because I have two lists, and a loop that does something like `a[i].foo( b[i])`.  I have always just accepted this as the way to do it, but if you know of some cool method that allows me to use foreach and keep `a` and `b` in sync, please let me know!  :)

Comment: @Dave: There are absolutely ways of doing that. Will edit. Glad to hear you've got the book on its way - hope you enjoy it!

Comment: gotcha, that makes sense.  I should have just tried to use MoveNext.  Thanks!